# Python in Ubuntu importing modules and files

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, import, git-bash

I need to import classes from models.py which is located in `myprojectdir/gaapp/models.py` to another python file located in `myprojectdir/dataUpdater/updateApi.py`, in Linux Ubuntu

**The code I have:**

```
from .models import FinalPage, FinalUser, Activity, Sessions, UserD, PageView, Event
```

**The error I get:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./updateApi.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .models import FinalPage, FinalUser, Activity, Sessions, UserD, PageView, Event
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Any suggestions?

EDITED:

```
(myprojectenv) llewellyn@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-ams3-01:~/myprojectdir/gaapp$ ls -la
total 84
drwxrwxr-x 8 llewellyn llewellyn  4096 May 13 15:04 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 llewellyn llewellyn  4096 May 13 13:06 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 llewellyn llewellyn  4096 May  7 08:52 .idea
-rw-rw-r-- 1 llewellyn llewellyn     0 May  7 07:21 __init__.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 llewellyn llewellyn  4096 May 13 14:30 __pycache__
-rwxrwxr-x 1 llewellyn llewellyn    86 May 12 17:39 admin.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 llewellyn llewellyn   194 May 13 13:25 apps.py
drwxrwxr-x 3 llewellyn llewellyn  4096 May  7 09:04 config
drwxrwxr-x 2 llewellyn llewellyn  4096 May 13 06:22 ga-credentials
drwxrwxr-x 3 llewellyn llewellyn  4096 May 13 07:15 migrations
-rw-rw-r-- 1 llewellyn llewellyn  2529 May 13 07:07 models.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 llewellyn llewellyn 12390 May 13 07:06 myprojectdir
drwxrwxr-x 3 llewellyn llewellyn  4096 May  7 09:28 templates
-rwxrwxr-x 1 llewellyn llewellyn    83 May 12 17:41 tests.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 llewellyn llewellyn     0 May 12 17:40 update.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 llewellyn llewellyn   265 May 13 11:01 urls.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 llewellyn llewellyn 16313 May 13 14:30 views.py
```

Comment: does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/llewellyn/myprojectdir/gaapp/')
import models
```

This what worked for me. Even though now I am getting a django error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./updateApi.py", line 27, in <module>
    import models
  File "/home/llewellyn/myprojectdir/gaapp/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class UserD(models.Model):
  File "/home/llewellyn/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 107, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/llewellyn/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/llewellyn/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/llewellyn/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/llewellyn/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 61, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your PYTHONPATH correctly. I'm guessing that you should set it to point to your `myprojectdir` directory. Then in your code you would say

```
from gaapp.models import FinalPage, FinalUser, Activity, Sessions, UserD, PageView, Event
```

Note that you will need an `__init__.py` in each directory or package from which you want to import modules.

The specific error you are getting is because you can't use relative imports (that begin with a `.`) in a main module. There's a long discussion about this here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/ but the upshot is that until/unless this is implemented, relative imports only work within a package.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./updateApi.py", line 23, in <module>
    from gaapp.models import FinalPage, FinalUser, Activity, Sessions, UserD, PageView, Event
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gaapp'
`

Comment: What is your PYTHONPATH set to? Did you create an `__init__.py` in all your packages?

Comment: I am trying to import models.py (im using django) .. so there is a __init__.py file within gaapp.. is that what you mean? Ill send the content now.. gaapp is the django app

Comment: Again, unless you set your PYTHONPATH to point to the right place, it will not work.

Comment: Also, I am coding this on a Linux server (using digital ocean) so Im not sure about the PATH. How do I set the PATH to point to the right place, when using a server

Comment: I don't know what a digital ocean is. If you run your code with `PYTHONPATH=/full/path/to/myprojectdir python3 updateApi.py` then it should work.

Comment: Okay cool. Is there a way to confirm the /full/path/to/my/myprojectdir

Comment: The command on Linux to show the path to your working directory is `pwd`

Comment: `PYTHONPATH=/home/llewellyn/myprojectdir/dataUpdater/ python3 updateApi.py
python3: can't open file 'updateApi.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
 `

Comment: Wow. Try this instead.
`PYTHONPATH=/home/llewellyn/myprojectdir/ python3 /home/llewellyn/myprojectdir/dataUpdater/updateApi.py`. You probably should get familiar with basic Linux things like changing directories before you try to deploy there.